# How to enable IIS compression for Web Services?

Tags: iis, compression

How do I enable compression for the Web Services request?

I've an IIS 6 server that, using the ISAPI filder from Apache, routes the incoming connection to a set of web application running on JBoss.

Because the routing happens using the AJP protocol we've decided to enable compression in IIS 6 enabling the "do" extension and the compression of the Html pages works perfectly.

Problem is that we also have a big part of the site that exposes a web service and, for this specific service, I do not have an extension to enable for compression, because all the request are in the form

```
http://servername:8080/name.WS/name
```

without having any extension.

How do I enable the IIS compression also for the connection to this url?

Regards

Massimo

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this walkthrough](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2004/01/12/IIS-Compression-in-IIS6.0.aspx)

However, the extensionless compression in IIS6 is going to be more difficult.  Since the URL is rewritten at the ISAPI Level I assume that it's actually hitting a URL with an exception, and it may work for you still.  Just make sure that the target page is compressed and the friendly URL shouldn't throw it off.